# If an access is repeated by the same user within one hour only the first is to be considered valid using MySQL

Tags: mysql

I need update the existing value on column `valid_access` on the table `dotable` using a database MySql version 5.7

```
+----+------------+----------+-----------+--------------+
| id | yyyy_mm_dd | hh_mm_ss | user_code | valid_access |
+----+------------+----------+-----------+--------------+
|  1 | 2021-08-02 | 00:39:31 | D29942    | NULL         |
|  2 | 2021-08-02 | 00:39:31 | D29942    | NULL         |
|  3 | 2021-08-02 | 01:07:36 | D29942    | NULL         |
|  4 | 2021-08-02 | 01:07:36 | D29942    | NULL         |
|  5 | 2021-08-02 | 01:23:33 | D29942    | NULL         |
|  6 | 2021-08-02 | 01:23:33 | D29942    | NULL         |
|  7 | 2021-08-02 | 02:44:00 | D29942    | NULL         |
+----+------------+----------+-----------+--------------+
```

I need this output

```
+----+------------+----------+-----------+--------------+
| id | yyyy_mm_dd | hh_mm_ss | user_code | valid_access |
+----+------------+----------+-----------+--------------+
|  1 | 2021-08-02 | 00:39:31 | D29942    | 1            |
|  2 | 2021-08-02 | 00:39:31 | D29942    | NULL         |
|  3 | 2021-08-02 | 01:07:36 | D29942    | NULL         |
|  4 | 2021-08-02 | 01:07:36 | D29942    | NULL         |
|  5 | 2021-08-02 | 01:23:33 | D29942    | NULL         |
|  6 | 2021-08-02 | 01:23:33 | D29942    | NULL         |
|  7 | 2021-08-02 | 02:44:00 | D29942    | 1            |
+----+------------+----------+-----------+--------------+
```

Because if an access is repeated by the same user within one hour only the first is to be considered valid.

Any suggestion?

My table structure and the update query below on [**db-fiddle.com**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jYfm36Zaf7Fw2ztxwDRsDG/1), which offers MySQL 5.7

Comment: You really have two records with exact same date and time (1 and 2)?

Comment: @SalmanA Unfortunately yes, but I'm not manages the stored logins. I just have to validate logins...

Comment: What happens if you have the three value `00:00`, `00:30`, `01:25`? The 3rd record has a previous entry that 55 minutes apart from 2nd but more than 1 hour from first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
UPDATE dotable t0
JOIN ( SELECT t1.id
       FROM dotable t1
       LEFT JOIN dotable t2 ON t2.id < t1.id
                           AND t2.user_code = t1.user_code
                           AND TIMESTAMP(t2.yyyy_mm_dd, t2.hh_mm_ss) <= TIMESTAMP(t1.yyyy_mm_dd, t1.hh_mm_ss)
                           AND TIMESTAMP(t2.yyyy_mm_dd, t2.hh_mm_ss) >= TIMESTAMP(t1.yyyy_mm_dd, t1.hh_mm_ss) - INTERVAL 1 HOUR 
       WHERE t2.id IS NULL) t3 USING (id)
SET valid_access = 1;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=814d46d262a5385ee9f0f5c62f34301d

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to mark the logons that are 1 hour apart, the query would be:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM dotable AS curr
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM dotable AS prev
    WHERE prev.user_code = curr.user_code
    AND TIMESTAMP(prev.yyyy_mm_dd, prev.hh_mm_ss) > TIMESTAMP(curr.yyyy_mm_dd, curr.hh_mm_ss) - INTERVAL 1 HOUR
    AND (
        TIMESTAMP(prev.yyyy_mm_dd, prev.hh_mm_ss) < TIMESTAMP(curr.yyyy_mm_dd, curr.hh_mm_ss)
        OR
        TIMESTAMP(prev.yyyy_mm_dd, prev.hh_mm_ss) = TIMESTAMP(curr.yyyy_mm_dd, curr.hh_mm_ss) AND prev.id < curr.id
    )
)
```

Comment: *I need **update** the existing value on column*...

Comment: @Akina replace select with update. I normally do not write update and delete queries because people so tend to copy-paste-execute the code without checking if it affects the desired rows or something else.

Comment: No. WHERE NOT EXISTS from the table which' column is updated is not allowed. The error `You can't specify target table 'tablename' for update in FROM clause` will be produced.